# Regex to remove consecutive sets of 1-2 characters separated by spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I am regex impaired, so I apologize for that, and want to thank, in advance, whoever can help me with this.

I have text as follows:

```
real text that i want to keep i e 2 2 1 i h i i i E h i L h R 9 more real text
i e 1 i tr L h R 1 i L ? i j 1 more real text that i want to keep d i j 0 etc...
```

You can see the sections of "junk" text that occur - these are what I want to remove. I'm not necessarily looking for 100% accuracy, but I'd like a regex that can get rid of most of these sections. I consider junk text to be any section with four or more consecutive occurrences of one or two characters, followed by a space.

As noted in the tags, I am working with c#. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you be more spcific what you would like to remove from a string? My guess is all what is connected with 1 and 2 when they are together (even in reverse order). Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\b(.{1,2}\s){4,}
```

You can obviously substitute the fullstop/period for a more exact match if you know what characters to allow.

Answer (score 2):

Just another regex solution: `(\s+(\S{1,2}(?=\s))){2,}`